# VBA Pivot deselect values to select a single value

Tags: vba, pivot

Im trying to create a VBA to eventually loop through a given list filtering out one value at a time from a Pivot table. The issue is with deselecting all options and choosing 1 value. How do you perform this?

The solution below (which i got to work is too slow):
What im trying below is to select the 1st value, then loop through the rest to deselect them and finally choosing the value i want. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
.PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(1).Visible = True
For i = 2 To .PivotItems.Count 'Error here
.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Name")
    .PivotItems(SelectedPerson).Visible = True
End With
End With
```

Comment: [.PivotFields(i).PivotItems.Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotitems)

Comment: Hi, i did see this comment, but i dont quite understand it.

Comment: `.PivotItems` in your code is referring to `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")` . It should refer to a PivotTable field. For example `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields(1).PivotItems.Count`

Comment: I would recommend deleting your below post. It is not an answer...

Comment: Even with this solution it is too slow, it would take me hours to wait for the entire data to loop through. Is there a way to "deselect" everything?

Comment: You mean like this? `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Name").ClearAllFilters`

Comment: Not quite, i have 100 items in a Pivot and all are selected as a default. I want to remove all 100 and select only 1, based on a cell value. I think your code above would remove a filter that is already in place.

Comment: Yes but then you can add the relevant filter back using `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Name").PivotFilters.Add 
Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="SOME VALUE"`

Comment: You want a faster method so.. **[1.]** Remove all filter. **[2.]** Add relevant filter. Isn't this what you are asking really?

Comment: See the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Converting all my relevant comments to an answer.

`.PivotItems` in your code is referring to `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")`. It should refer to a PivotTable field. For example

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields(1).PivotItems.Count
'~~> OR something like
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Name").PivotItems.Count
```

You can read more about it in [PivotItems object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotitems)

> Even with this solution it is too slow, it would take me hours to wait for the entire data to loop through. Is there a way to "deselect" everything?

For a faster method, you can remove all filter in one go (without looping) and then simply add the relevant filter as shown below

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

'~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
Set ws = Sheet1

With ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Name")
    .ClearAllFilters

    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, _
                      Value1:="SOME VALUE"
                      '~~> OR something like
                      '~~> Value1:= ws.Range("A1").Value
End With
```

> Tried both referencing a cell and direct text in VBA. Is it possible that the value is somehow formattet wrongly in the pivot data? As in text in my cell im refering to but something else in the Pivot? – Carlsberg789 24 mins ago

**Screenshot in action**

[image]

Comment: This works fine untill the .PivotFilters.Add, where i get Run-time error 1004 for some reason. Only part i changed was: Value1:="FirstName,LastName,FF92892"

Comment: You cannot add multiple items like that. You may want to see [PivotFilters.Add method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfilters.add)

Comment: Ahh, they are not actually multiple items but just a single value that is on a single cell. So the value in cell would be: John,Smith,US2988 or does VBA understand the commas in between that it means multiple values?

Comment: Ensure that it is the exact text or best use the relevant cell `Value1:= ws.Range("A1").Value` as mentioned in the code above'

Comment: I did ensure, it is exactly the same as the one that works if i do it manually. Tried both referencing a cell and direct text in VBA. Is it possible that the value is somehow formattet wrongly in the pivot data? As in text in my cell im refering to but something else in the Pivot?

Comment: The code that I gave is tried and tested. Few things that you can verify. **[1.]** Refresh the table manually once by right clicking on it and clickin on refresh
**[2.]** You have the correct field name
**[3.]** Click the cell which has the text and check if the address of the cell is correct
**[4.]** Also check you are referencing the correct worksheet

Comment: I have added a screenshot. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Ahh, i think i see the issue now. Ive been working with the PivotTable FieldList (the pop-up screen on the right, with a specified Filter-box. I have my filter in there, rather filtering the PivotTable itself. Is it easy to create the same filter over there? I have an extensive amount of code that works with the current Pivot table setting, so changing this would be quite a job.. :)

Comment: I am afraid there, you will have to loop. You cannot use `.ClearAllFilters` there. You could use a loop and sandwich your code between `ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ManualUpdate = True` and `ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ManualUpdate = False` You can also use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to speed up the code?